# Opencv and c++ Fisherface algorithm always predict wrong even with the exactly same image as input and reconstruct a black image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, face-recognition

So as the title says, i'm having a problem when working with opencv on c++ using interface of Windows forms only to send the input for the actions on the program, basically i save the treated images on a folder and recover them without any problem i even checked like a hundred times if there was any problem when i recover the images and no, there is nothing wrong there, so i started testing the output image that the program was giving and i realized that the reconstructed image taken from the FaceRecognizer was completely black, i tried to change the declarations but nothing changes, and what is funny is that this same algorith Works on another Project that i created as a testing and there is no interface there, only the console so the program is running on the main function, and in this testing Project when i reconstruct the image from the face FaceRecognizer it returns a normal face image and it recognize the correct face, but on the new Project with interface i use the same image as input and it recognizes all wrong and also reconstruct the black image, i think that is something wrong with the FaceRecognizer model but i have no idea  what it is exactly! can anyone help me?

Here is the code to recover the images from the folder:

```
            if (traiModel)
            {
                // read all folders on the images and for each one give an number id
                // read the images for each folder and add on a vector of images
                // read the folder name and give to all images to set the label info
                Preprocessed_Faces.clear();
                faceLabels.clear();
                Preprocessed_Faces_Names.clear();

                std::string folder = "TrainingFolder\\";
                std::vector<cv::string> foldernames;
                foldernames = get_all_files_names_within_folder(folder);
                std::vector<int> labels;
                for (int f = 0; f < foldernames.size(); f++)
                {
                    std::string thisfoldername = folder + foldernames[f];
                    std::vector<cv::string> filenames;
                    cv::glob(thisfoldername, filenames);
                    Preprocessed_Faces_Names.push_back(foldernames[f]);
                    labels.push_back(f + 1);
                    for (int fn = 0; fn < filenames.size(); fn++)
                    {
                        Preprocessed_Faces.push_back(cv::imread(filenames[fn]));
                        //std::cout << filenames[fn] << std::endl;
                        faceLabels.push_back(f + 1);
                    }
                }

                cv::imwrite("Traintest.PNG", Preprocessed_Faces[0]);

                std::map<int, std::string> map1;
                for (int i = 0; i < Preprocessed_Faces_Names.size(); i++)
                {
                    map1.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(labels[i], Preprocessed_Faces_Names[i]));
                    std::cout << Preprocessed_Faces_Names[i] << std::endl;
                }
                model->setLabelsInfo(map1);
                model->train(Preprocessed_Faces, faceLabels);
                traiModel = false;
            }
```

Here is the code for identify the face he tries to reconstruct the face first and identify:

```
        if (identif)
        {
            // identify the current face looking on the database
            // Prediction Validation
            // Get some required data from the FaceRecognizer model.
            cv::Mat eigenvectors = model->get<cv::Mat>("eigenvectors");
            cv::Mat averageFaceRow = model->get<cv::Mat>("mean");

            // Project the input image onto the eigenspace.
            cv::Mat projection = cv::subspaceProject(eigenvectors, averageFaceRow, filtered.reshape(1, 1));

            // Generate the reconstructed face back from the eigenspace.
            cv::Mat reconstructionRow = cv::subspaceReconstruct(eigenvectors, averageFaceRow, projection);

            // Make it a rectangular shaped image instead of a single row.
            cv::Mat reconstructionMat = reconstructionRow.reshape(1, filtered.rows);

            // Convert the floating-point pixels to regular 8-bit uchar.
            cv::Mat reconstructedFace = cv::Mat(reconstructionMat.size(), CV_8U);
            reconstructionMat.convertTo(reconstructedFace, CV_8U, 1, 0);

            cv::imwrite("Teste.PNG", filtered);
            cv::imwrite("Teste2.PNG", reconstructedFace);

            int identity = model->predict(filtered);
            double similarity = getSimilarity(filtered, reconstructedFace);
            if (similarity > .7f)
            {
                //identity = -1; // -1 means that the face is not registred in the trainer
            }
            std::cout << "This is: " << identity << " and: " << model->getLabelInfo(identity) << std::endl;
            identif = false;
        }
```

here is the code where the complete loop for identifying a face runs and also the declaration of the FaceRecognizer the 2 odes above are in there:

```
void RecognitionAlgo::Running()
{
    // Create the cascade classifier object used for the face detection
    cv::CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    // Use the haarcascade frontalface_alt.xml library
    if (!face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"))
    {
        Log("Error at face Cascade Load!")
    }


    // Setup image files used in the capture process
    cv::Mat captureFrame;
    cv::Mat grayscaleFrame;
    cv::Mat shrinkFrame;


    // Create a vector to store the face found
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> Preprocessed_Faces;
    std::vector<cv::string> Preprocessed_Faces_Names;
    cv::string myname;
    std::vector<int> faceLabels;

    // Init the face Recognizer
    cv::initModule_contrib();

    std::string facerecAlgorithm = "FaceRecognizer.Fisherfaces";
    cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> model;
    // Use OpenCV's new FaceRecognizer in the "contrib" module;
    model = cv::Algorithm::create<cv::FaceRecognizer>(facerecAlgorithm);
    if (model.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: FaceRecognizer" << std::endl;
    }
    try
    {
        //model->load("TrainedModel.xml");
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {

    }

    // Create a loop to caoture and find faces
    while (true)
    {
        // Capture a new image frame
        if (swCamera)
        {
            captureDevice >> captureFrame;
        }
        else
        {
            captureFrame = cv::imread("face3.PNG");
        }

        // Shrink the captured image, Convert to gray scale and equalize
        cv::cvtColor(captureFrame, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::equalizeHist(grayscaleFrame, grayscaleFrame);
        shrinkFrame = ShrinkingImage(grayscaleFrame);

        // Find faces on the shrink image (because it's faster) and store them in the vector array
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale(shrinkFrame, faces, 1.1, 4, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30));

        if (faces.size() > 0)
            faces = EnlargeResults(captureFrame, faces);

        // Draw a rectangle for all found faces in the vector array on original image
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
            cv::Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);

            cv::Mat theFace = grayscaleFrame(faces[i]);

            // try to treat the face by identifying the eyes, if the eyes fail to detect, it returns theface
            cv::Mat filtered = TreatmentForFace(theFace);

            // Collecting faces and learning from them.

            if (starTraining && TrainName != "")
            {
                if (colFace)
                {
                    Preprocessed_Faces.push_back(filtered);
                    if (myname == "")
                    {
                        myname = TrainName;
                    }
                    colFace = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!starTraining && Preprocessed_Faces.size() > 0)
                {
                    // create the person folder
                    std::string command = "mkdir ";
                    std::string foldercom = "TrainingFolder\\" + myname;
                    command += foldercom;
                    system(command.c_str());

                    // create a string to access the recent created folder
                    std::string foldername = foldercom.substr(0, foldercom.size() - (myname.size() + 1));
                    foldername.append("/");
                    foldername.append(myname);
                    foldername.append("/");
                    foldername.append(myname);
                    // save the colected faces on the folder
                    for (int i = 0; i < Preprocessed_Faces.size(); i++)
                    {
                        std::ostringstream oss;
                        oss << i;
                        cv::imwrite(foldername + oss.str() + ".PNG", Preprocessed_Faces[i]);
                    }
                    myname = "";
                    Preprocessed_Faces.clear();
                }
            }

            if (traiModel)
            {
                // read all folders on the images and for each one give an number id
                // read the images for each folder and add on a vector of images
                // read the folder name and give to all images to set the label info
                Preprocessed_Faces.clear();
                faceLabels.clear();
                Preprocessed_Faces_Names.clear();

                std::string folder = "TrainingFolder\\";
                std::vector<cv::string> foldernames;
                foldernames = get_all_files_names_within_folder(folder);
                std::vector<int> labels;
                for (int f = 0; f < foldernames.size(); f++)
                {
                    std::string thisfoldername = folder + foldernames[f];
                    std::vector<cv::string> filenames;
                    cv::glob(thisfoldername, filenames);
                    Preprocessed_Faces_Names.push_back(foldernames[f]);
                    labels.push_back(f + 1);
                    for (int fn = 0; fn < filenames.size(); fn++)
                    {
                        Preprocessed_Faces.push_back(cv::imread(filenames[fn]));
                        //std::cout << filenames[fn] << std::endl;
                        faceLabels.push_back(f + 1);
                    }
                }

                cv::imwrite("Traintest.PNG", Preprocessed_Faces[0]);

                std::map<int, std::string> map1;
                for (int i = 0; i < Preprocessed_Faces_Names.size(); i++)
                {
                    map1.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(labels[i], Preprocessed_Faces_Names[i]));
                    std::cout << Preprocessed_Faces_Names[i] << std::endl;
                }
                model->setLabelsInfo(map1);
                model->train(Preprocessed_Faces, faceLabels);
                traiModel = false;
            }

            if (identif)
            {
                // identify the current face looking on the database
                // Prediction Validation
                // Get some required data from the FaceRecognizer model.
                cv::Mat eigenvectors = model->get<cv::Mat>("eigenvectors");
                cv::Mat averageFaceRow = model->get<cv::Mat>("mean");

                // Project the input image onto the eigenspace.
                cv::Mat projection = cv::subspaceProject(eigenvectors, averageFaceRow, filtered.reshape(1, 1));

                // Generate the reconstructed face back from the eigenspace.
                cv::Mat reconstructionRow = cv::subspaceReconstruct(eigenvectors, averageFaceRow, projection);

                // Make it a rectangular shaped image instead of a single row.
                cv::Mat reconstructionMat = reconstructionRow.reshape(1, filtered.rows);

                // Convert the floating-point pixels to regular 8-bit uchar.
                cv::Mat reconstructedFace = cv::Mat(reconstructionMat.size(), CV_8U);
                reconstructionMat.convertTo(reconstructedFace, CV_8U, 1, 0);

                cv::imwrite("Teste.PNG", filtered);
                cv::imwrite("Teste2.PNG", reconstructedFace);

                int identity = model->predict(filtered);
                double similarity = getSimilarity(filtered, reconstructedFace);
                if (similarity > .7f)
                {
                    //identity = -1; // -1 means that the face is not registred in the trainer
                }
                std::cout << "This is: " << identity << " and: " << model->getLabelInfo(identity) << std::endl;
                identif = false;
            }
        }

        // Print the output
        cv::resize(captureFrame, captureFrame, cv::Size(800, 600));
        cv::imshow("outputCapture", captureFrame);
        // pause for 33ms
        cv::waitKey(33);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV FaceRecognizer is implemented to be used with grayscale images. The problem is where you are reading the images from disk using cv::imread().

```
(cv::imread(filenames[fn]));
```

Even though you might have grayscale images saved, imread() by default loads 3 channel images. Specify CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE as shown below.

```
(cv::imread(filenames[fn],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));
```